# How to verify if an argument passed is with correct parameters if that argument's state is changed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to verify the object by using

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<User> userArgumentCaptor
...//define user with name and jailName - var = user1
...//Call the method under test.
verify(userDao).getName(userArgumentCaptor.capture());
verify(userDai).getJailName(userArgumentCaptor.capture());
assertThat(userArgumentCaptor.getAllValues()).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(user1user1));
/**
* Notice here that I had to use same object to verify even when I captured it in two different situations.
*/
```

for the scenario,

```
User user = new User(); //Object under inspection.
user.setId(); //Changing state here.
userDao.getName(user); //Capture user here.
...
if(someBooleanCondition) {
    user.setJailStatus(true); //Changing state here.
    userDao.getJailName(user); //Capture user here.
}
```

While asserting the `userArgumentCaptor.getValue()`, it is checking the updated value. This actually makes sense since I'm capturing the object not object's state.

But, how do I verify the object's state when it was passed?

Comment: Can you provide your test code? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Sure. So was I. That is why I keep adding those ;-) ... just to make sure the fun comes over ... it is lost too often when doing the comment-chat thing here ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible. Even when checking out the very latest version of [ArgumentCaptor](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.21) (mockito 2.7.21 at this point); there is no indication at all to go in that direction.

The purpose respectively service offered by ArgumentCaptor is to collect those parameters used when a method is called.

What you are asking is basically: is there a way to do **additional** checking at the point when that call **happens**.

I guess, it could be made possible: the framework would have to allow you to register a callback, that is called whenever a specific method is invoked on a mock object. But that isn't possible today.

The only solution I see - instead of doing

```
@Mock
YourRealDaoClass theMockedDao
```

You would have to do

```
class MockedDaoClass extends YourRealDaoClass {
```

and then implement such things **yourself**. So that you can put:

```
YourRealDaoClass theMockedDao = new MockedDaoClass(...
```

into your tests. Together with a some other logic to enable the things you need.

In other words: the mocks generated by Mockito do not allow you to do enhanced testing at the point when methods are invoked on mocked objects. If you need that (for example to do a test like: `param.getFoo().equals()`) then you are back to creating your own stub/mock class.

What you have to do:

- carefully check all the methods that the Dao class has
- decide which one you need to overwrite, to make sure that they return the values you need to make the mock work with your production code
- for the methods that receive those parameters you are interested in: either do checking right there; or collect the values for later checking

Comment: Wait, Could you elaborate upon the extending and implementing?

Comment: I enhanced my answer. But thing is: this is more of a theoretical answer. I haven't written stubs/mock classes myself yet. Hope this is good enough to get you going. If not, drop me a comment ...

Comment: I'm trying to see if it works for me and how to do it.

Comment: The thing here is, even if I implement `MockedDaoClass` I wouldn't be changing the state of the parameter in that class. I'm changing outside. That is being reflected. Seems like I should clarify this in question.

Comment: I think I got that: the point is: your version of that method could **query** that state you are interested in and somehow remember that. Meaning: the argument captor can only record the objects given to method calls. But when you **write** the code in that method; what prevents you from recording something that you **retrieve** from the parameters given to your method?

Comment: Okay. Got it. Unfortunately, this is an internship. I'm not allowed to change the production code. The task is just to write unit tests.

I thought of creating a `MockUserClass` and whenever I needed it I could create a new object and store the state of `User` object and capture the arguments. Even this meant I had to change the code to include an extra class just for testing, change parameters or use PowerMockito to mock my `new MockUserClass`, none of which seem very nice.

Comment: Sorry. Sounds like one important part of your internship is to explain to that team that "hiring an intern from time to time to do unit testing" does **not** work in reality. If you don't write your production code to be testable ... surprise: it becomes hard to test. Maybe you should share this link https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 with those people.